# AWS/CloudTrail - Why its not mentioned in AWS Namespaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, namespaces, amazon-cloudtrail

Clearly AWS/Cloudtrail is available in AWS NameSpace as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/N_Amazon_CloudTrail.htm

Why is it not provided in official documentation list of AWS namespaces?
URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

The CloudWatch namespace is not related with the .NET namespace. As mentioned in the [second URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-namespaces.html):

> CloudWatch namespaces are containers for metrics. Metrics in different
>   namespaces are isolated from each other, so that metrics from
>   different applications are not mistakenly aggregated into the same
>   statistics.

Please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) for CloudTrail APIs.